What is the difference between these two values of derivatives?

Rate of change of radius $R$ of a sphere is $2 \ \text{m/s}$. What is rate of change of volume $V$ when $R = 3 \ \text{m}$?
The solution is:
$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3 \quad \text{and} \quad R = 2t$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t} \\
&= 4\pi R^2 \times 2 \\
&= 8 \pi R^2
\end{align}
At $R = 3$, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = 72\pi.$

But if I find $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R}$ instead, I get half of the above answer:
$$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3\\ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R} = 4 \pi R^2$$
At $R = 3$, rate of change of $V$ is $36\pi$.
In both cases, the radius is changing. Then what's the difference between $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R}$ ?

@YvesDaoust I do not mean that I am expecting the same answers. What I mean is, I want to understand the difference between the two, in terms of their physical meaning

Do you want the rate of change with respect to time or the radius?

"Rate of change of Volume with respect to Radius" vs. "Rate of changecof Volume with respect to Time".  And radius changes twice as fast as time.

@AndyWalls how slow or how fast will the radius have to change with respect to time such that dV/dR and dV/dt will have the same value? I am trying to understand the difference between dV/dR and dV/dt in terms of their physical meaning. Thank you.

@AlvinL As I have mentioned, I am not able to grasp the difference between dV/dR and dV/dt. How are they different in terms of their physical meaning in this particular snenario?

$\displaystyle\frac{{\rm d}V}{{\rm d}R}$ has a '${\rm m}^2$' unit and $\displaystyle\frac{{\rm d}V}{{\rm d}t}$ has a '${\rm m}^3/{\rm s}$'. Does this help you understand?

Consider a sphere, of radius $R$ and volume $V,$ that is getting bigger as time passes. Then as $t$ is increasing, $R$ and $V$ are continually correspondingly increasing.
However, the sphere's volume and radius are not generally increasing by the same numerical amount per unit time. In other words, the rates of change of $\boldsymbol V$ and $R$ (with respect to time) aren't generally equal. That is, $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}\not\equiv \dfrac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$ This is equivalent to saying that $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R}\not\equiv1.$$ In yet other words, the rate of change of $\boldsymbol V$ with respect to $\boldsymbol R$ (that is, how much $V$ changes per unit change in $R)$ doesn't generally equal $1.$
(Except at the exact instant when $R=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{\pi}}.)$
In your example, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}$ has a fixed value $2$ as time passes,  whereas both $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}R}$ vary with their independent variables (becoming $2$ and $1,$ respectively, precisely when $t=\dfrac1{4\sqrt\pi}).$
